# Displaying a web page inside another without frames

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to display a webpage inside another website page. How safe is the approach below, and how good practice is this?

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px;"><object type="text/html" data="http://answers.yahoo.com/" style="width:100%; height:400px; margin:1%;"></object></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a frame?

Answer (score 0):

It will, effectively, be an iframe with fewer features and weaker support.

Use an iframe instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFrames if not frames. Alternatively you can use AJAX or cURL functionality in server side.